# How can I avoid changes in DB while making a set of queries?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, transactions

In my web application (Java + Spring + JPA) I have a method executing a set of related queries. In particular I need to know the total row count of a table and the row count of the result set for a certain query.

Obviously between these two queries changes can happen in my table: a new row added, row removed, field value changed, etc.

Table has millions of rows, so it's impossible to load the whole table in memory and make filtering in application context.

So I need to find a way to execute a set of queries maintaining the same "state" for the table (some kind of snapshot).
Is it sufficient to execute queries inside the same transaction, or is there some other approach?

**UPDATE**
The method is used for table pagination. I need to show *n* rows (PAGE) taken from *m* pages (SEARCH) filtered from a a total of *t* existing rows (TOTAL).

So basically I need to extract n records and to provide two numeric info: filtered rows count and total rows count.

I can execute `SELECT count(*) from table`, then `SELECT count(*) from table where <search criteria>` and then `SELECT * from table where <search criteria> limit <n>`, but I must be sure that no change appens in between...

I'm using MySQL 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My tests in MySQL 5.5.28 show that you could rely on the fact simply being in a transaction won't count any new inserted/deleted/changed rows (being in a  `REPEATABLE READ` transaction isolation level). This means, that COUNT() is subject to the transaction isolation levels. According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-transaction.html) this mode is exactly what you want: a snapshot-based read based on the first read.